# Check for input array if it's empty or not - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have an input looks like this.

```
{!! Form::text('inventory[0][amount]', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::text('inventory[0][expiry_date]', null, ['data-format'=>'D, dd MM yyyy', 'class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

`print_r( $_POST )` results

```
[inventory] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [amount] => 66 [expiry_date] => 2019/05/20 ) )
```

I am trying to check if the `amount` and the `expiry_date` are not `null`

```
if ( $input['inventory[0][amount]'] and $input['inventory[0][expiry_date]'] != null )
```

Got

> Undefined index: inventory[0][amount]

Comment: try `$request->has('inventory[0][amount]')`

Comment: `$input['inventory'][0]['amount']` See the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way with `!empty()`,

```
if (!empty($_POST['inventory'][0]['amount']) && !empty($_POST['inventory'][0]['expiry_date']))
{ 
    //You code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dot notation and `$request->filled($keys)` to achieve this...

`$request->filled(['inventory.0.amount', 'inventory.0.expiry_date'])`

Will return `true` if amount and expiry_date are present and not empty.

For example, assuming you want to perform the check in your controller...

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// ...

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->filled(['inventory.0.amount', 'inventory.0.expiry_date'])) {
            // Both amount and expiry_date are present and not empty...
            // You can also use the request() helper if you don't want inject the Request class...
        }
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest that unless you have multiple inventory items, i.e `inventory[n]['amount']` - you change the input name to `inventory[amount]`.

This means that you can do the following:

```php
$request->filled('inventory.amount') // or (isset($input['inventory']['amount']) && ! empty($input['inventory']['amount']))
```

---

#### Edit

`filled()` was introduced in 5.5, it should be replaced with `has()` in 5.4.

Comment: I got `Method filled does not exist.`!

Comment: Whoops, `filled` is a 5.5+ method. it should be replaced with `has` in 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the array key properly, Replace your code with

```
$arr = array(
 'inventory' => Array (
  0 => Array (
     'amount' => 66,
     'expiry_date' => '2019/05/20'
  ) 
 )
);

if($arr['inventory'][0]['amount'] and $arr['inventory'][0]['expiry_date'] != ''){
```

Comment: Where this `$arr` come from

Comment: @YousefAltaf `$arr` means `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

There is no key with name `'inventory[0][amount]'` in this array so it would be checked like this:

```
if(array_key_exists('inventory',$input) &&  
     array_key_exists(0,$input['inventory'])  &&  
     array_key_exists('amount',$input['inventory'][0])  && 
       !empty($input['inventory'][0]['amount'])
//add for expiry too
 ){

}
```